What are those other usb root_hubs on my system
I have a brand new framework 16 laptop and was wandering if i could route a certain usb controller to a VM for use with a music software only available under Windows (So a Linux host system and a Windows VM is the setup i want, no dual-boot), I checked with lsusb to see if there where more than 1 usb controllers and I got this output :
/:  Bus 001.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Billboard, Driver=[none], 12M
    |__ Port 001: Dev 002, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 002: Dev 003, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 003: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 006, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 006, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 006, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 006, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 004: Dev 005, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 008, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=[none], 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 002: Dev 009, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 005: Dev 007, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
    |__ Port 005: Dev 007, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
    |__ Port 005: Dev 007, If 2, Class=Wireless, Driver=[none], 480M
/:  Bus 002.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 002: Dev 002, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 10000M
        |__ Port 001: Dev 004, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 003.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 004.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 005.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 006.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 007.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 008.Port 001: Dev 001, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M


I checked with a usb stick every port and it appears only on bus 1 and 2, not the others.
I admit I don't have that much knowledge on how Linux deal with usb but I want to know if those usb controllers can be accessed and if so, can be pass-through to a VM
PS :
I'm using EndeavorOS Galileo-Neo with GNOME.

IIRC certain container platform configs or VM setups create virtual USB hubs that the host can use for USB passthrough. Also, most laptops have multiple USB hubs because the ports are physically in different places. Given your laptop's modularity, I'd say that's probably why there are so many.
But as an aside, I recently got Proton working through Steam specifically for music production software and it was actually quite easy and works really well. Would def recommend

I just ran lsusb -t on my own system and have an output of similar length
